# Selenium IDE javascript Click Element if stored variable = Yes

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

What I want to do is to cause Selenium IDE to click a tick box if a stored value 'x' equals Yes.

I have tried the below but it advises that Yes is not defined.

Also I am unsure which Selenium IDE command to use for this action.

Any help is appreciated :)

```
click|

javascript{if(storedVars['x']==Yes){this.browserbot.findElement('id=includesSlowerTrains').click();}} |
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: WITHOUT EXTENSION:
I've tried it on google.com:

```
storeElementPresent id=gbqfbb x
click javascript{if(storedVars['x'] == true){this.browserbot.findElement('id=gbqfbb').click();}}
```

Try it for yourself :)

I would suggest using `goto_sel_ide` extension, available online. `storeElementPresent` might be also a useful command. It stores in `boolean` variable, if specific element is present or not. Try following code:

```
storeElementPresent tickbox x
gotoIf ${x}==true variableXequalsTrue
gotoIf ${x}==false variableXequalsFalse
label variableXequalsTrue //your script will go right here if element "tickbox" is present
click yourElement
goto afterTickbox
label variableXequalsFalse //your script will go right here if element "tickbox" is NOTpresent
//todo, if element is not present
goto afterTickbox
label afterTickbox
```

Comment: Thanks for you help.
I was trying to avoid using an extension, and just use javascript if possible

Comment: Then try your code with `storeElementPresent` :)
From what i read, you didn't know this command. Try to store your element in x and then, use your javascript.